# Need vr using div tag, but it is not going 100% height

Tags: html, css

Looking for a vertical ruler using a div tag. and  I want something like this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Loz88.png

My code **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8kdLn5ys/)**

CSS:

```
.acc{
    float:left;
    width:400px;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:#FFF solid 3px;
    background-color:#319dba;
}
.acc .title{
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:5px;
    border-bottom:3px #FFFFFF solid;
}

.acc .debit{
    float:left;
    width:198px;
    height:auto;
}
.acc .vr{
    float:left;
    width:2px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #fff;
}
.acc .credit{
    float:right;
    width:198px;
    height:auto;
}
.acc .row{
    width:100%;
    height:25px;

}
```

But vr does not going for 100% height. 
help me. 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8kdLn5ys/7/)**

CSS:

```
 .acc {
    float:left;
    width:400px;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:#FFF solid 3px;
    background-color:#319dba;
    position: relative;
}
.acc .title {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:5px;
    border-bottom:3px #FFFFFF solid;
}
.acc .debit {
    float:left;
    width:198px;
    height:auto;
}
.acc .vr {
    width:2px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#f00;
    border:1px solid #f00;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left:50%;
}
.acc .credit {
    float:right;
    width:198px;
    height:auto;
}
.acc .row {
    width:100%;
    height:25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a vr div, apply a border to the left element:

```
.acc .debit {
  border-right: 3px solid white;
}
```

That is also how the upper hr has been made.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kdLn5ys/2/)

If you don't want to bother with width, you can apply half the border from the left and half from the other side or switch box-sizing.

Comment: It won't work when one side's height is greater than the other. in your case  if debit side's height is 150px and credit sides's height is 200px, then 50px  height border will missing..